# Sequence regarding smallest prime divisors

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

My friend Agamjeet Singh came up with the following question:

> Let $\lambda(a)$ denote the smallest prime factor of $a$. Consider an infinite sequence $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ of positive integers such that $$a_{i+2}=\lambda(a_{i+1})\lambda(a_i)+1,$$ for all positive integers $i$. Is this sequence bounded, regardless of the values of $a_1$ and $a_2$?

I believe that the answer is affirmative. I will leave my progress below.

To begin with, if the sequence $(\lambda(a_n))_{n\geqslant 1}$ is bounded, then so is $(a_n)_{n\geqslant 1}.$ Hence, it suffices to show that the former is bounded and from now on, we will only work with this sequence. We may also assume that the first and second terms of the sequence are $2$ and some prime number $p$, in some order.

Let $p_k$ denote the $k^{\text{th}}$ prime number. We can easily see that our sequence will be of the form $$\ldots, \ 2, \ p_{i_1}, \ p_{i_2}, \ 2, \ p_{i_3}, \ p_{i_4}, \ 2, \ \ p_{i_5}, \ p_{i_6}, \ 2,\ldots$$
Assume that any sequence generated by $(2,k)$ and $(k,2)$ with $k\leqslant p_n$ is eventually bounded. Also, assume that the sequence generated by $(2,p)$ where $p=p_{n+1}$ is unbounded (the case when the sequence is generated by $(p_{n+1},2)$ is analogous). Then, every prime number in this sequence will be greater than $p_n$. Call this property $(\dagger).$ Let our sequence be $$2, \ \ p, \ p_{i_1}, \ 2, \ p_{i_2}, \ p_{i_3}, \ 2, \ \ p_{i_4}, \ p_{i_5}, \ 2,\ldots$$
We claim that for any $t<\log_2(p^2+1)-\log_2(p+1):=C,$ we have $p_{i_t}=2^{t}(p+1)-1.$

Note that $p_1=\lambda(2p+1)$ and if $2p+1$ is not composite, then all of it's prime factors would be $<p$ which is a contradiction to $(\dagger).$ Hence, $p_1=2p+1=2^1(p+1)-1$ so the base case holds. Now, assume that $k+1<C$ and that $p_{i_k}=2^{k}(p+1)-1.$ Then, notice that $$p_{i_{k+1}}=\lambda\big(2\big(2^k(p+1)-1\big)+1\big)=\lambda\big(2^{k+1}(p+1)-1\big)$$ and since $k+1<C$ then $2^{k+1}(p+1)-1<p^2$ so if it isn't a prime, then the smallest prime factor of $2^{k+1}(p+1)-1$ would be smaller than $p$ which is yet again a contradiction to $(\dagger).$ Therefore, we now know that $$2(p+1)-1, \ 2^2(p+1)-1, ..., \ 2^{\lfloor C\rfloor}(p+1)-1$$are all prime numbers. In simpler words, $2^i(p+1)-1$ is always prime for $2^i<p$.

Since $2^{k}(p+1)-1,...,2^{\lfloor C\rfloor}(p+1)-1$ are all primes, this means that there are at least $\lfloor C\rfloor-k+1$ primes smaller than $p^2$ which are congruent to $-1$ modulo $2^k(p+1).$ This yields $$\pi\big(p^2;2^k(p+1),-1\big)\geqslant\lfloor C\rfloor-k+1\approx\lfloor\log_2 p\rfloor-k+1$$where $\pi(x; n,m)$ denotes the number of primes smaller than $x$ congruent to $m$ modulo $n$. I tried to reach a contradiction by bounding, but failed. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks to me like $2,3$ continues $7,22$, not $7,2$ as you say.  There is no $\lambda$ around the expression on the right in your recurrence.  Did you mean to have one?

Comment: No, I did not mean to have one, but as I stated in the first paragraph, it suffices to work (and we do work) with the sequence $\lambda(a_i)$. Formally, one would re-define $a_i$ as $a_{i+1}=\lambda(\lambda(a_i)\lambda(a_{i-1})+1)$.

Comment: I don't see why it is true that $\lambda(a_i)$ being bounded implies that $a_i$ is bounded.  Those $2$s in the $\lambda(a_i)$ sequence could multiply increasingly larger numbers.

Comment: Suppose $\lambda(a_i)$ is bounded by $M$, then $a_{i+1}=\lambda(a_i)\lambda(a_{i-1})+1<M^2+1$ hence $a_i$ is bounded by $\max(a_1,a_2,M^2+1$).

Comment: Without having tried concrete examples , I would expect sequences with huge entries. Of course , there is an upper bound for $a_{i+2}$ depending on $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ , namely $max(a_i,a_{i+1})^2+1$ , but this does not prevent the sequence to "explode".

Comment: I also expect huge entries, but I do think that for large enough primes $p$ we may be able to find $2^i<p$ such that $2^i(p+1)-1$ is not prime.